# Spring Aspectj LoadTimeWeaving is not working

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have a problem weaving an aspect using AspectJ LoadTimeWeaving

Here is the aspect:

```
package com.thomson.tgr.aspects;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

@Aspect
public class PerformanceAspect {

@Around("methodsToBeProfiled()")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch(getClass().getSimpleName());
    try {
        sw.start(pjp.getSignature().getName());
        return pjp.proceed();
    } finally {
        sw.stop();
        System.out.println("asdfasdf" + sw.prettyPrint());
    }
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..))")
public void methodsToBeProfiled(){}
```

}

here is the aop.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
    "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
```

```
<weaver options="-verbose -debug -showWeaveInfo">        
    <include within="com..*"/>

</weaver>

<aspects>

    <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
    <aspect name="com.xxx.tgr.aspects.PerformanceAspect"/>

</aspects>
```

I've added

```
<context:load-time-weaver />
```

to my beans definition.

and i added

```
-javaagent:"C:/Users/UC193514/Desktop/aspectjweaver-1.7.0.jar"
-javaagent:"C:/Users/UC193514/Desktop/spring-instrument-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar"
```

To the JVM arguments.

all what i can see related to weaving in my log is:

```
[WebappClassLoader@1ce4a8a] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
```

no class has been weaved.

Did i miss anything??

Comment: You can only specify a single javaagent afaik, not multiple. Also the warning states that the default idk classes will not be weaved. Depending on the server you don't need the agent and only `@EnableLoadtimeWeaving` or `<context:loadtime-weaving />`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, Actually i have tried to use single agent and didnt work, i've read some articles which say that both agents should be used. i am using Tomcat server, deploying from Eclipse